# Can you use WFS services in a front-end Cesium app?

Tags: wfs, wfs-t, cesium, ol-cesium

I am using Web Map Services (WMS) in Cesium Apps

[.WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider.html)

[.WebMapServiceImageryProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/WebMapServiceImageryProvider.html)

However I cannot find any Cesium official reference to WFS or WFS-T services which I now need to start using.

I have visited this site regarding OpenLayers and Cesium integration:

[ol-cesium](https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/)

but no explicit reference to WFS services as such, only to 'vectors' examples (i.e. JSON).

Is there any implementation of the [WFS standard](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) for Cesium?

Comment: Just curious if you ever got anywhere with this? I have a GeoServer instance serving up some WFS stuff, and I'm shopping web globes. I like a lot about Cesium so far, but not being able to use WFS could be a problem. Thanks much!

Comment: The only progress so far is to force the geoserver geometry output as 'json' in the WFS call, and you could use that within the Geojson class in Cesium. The problem is that the json output in Geoserver in this way it returns a file and it could be very, very large. This problem has been addressed by the Cesium developers by using a 'promise' -javascript language- approach which can deal with unresolved URLs and/or broken download links. But, still this is not by any means a proper WFS service.

Comment: @Web-GISentrepreneur your comment should probably be the answer

Comment: i don't think there is any WFS standar in Cesium so far. But you can resolve this by creating xmlHttp request with output format jsonp and parsing it using parse.JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 'outputFormat=application/json' in the WFS call to Geoserver, the outfile could be used as source for the 'Geojson' class in Cesium. The problem is that the json file could be very, very large. Besides you can use CQL filters to make your geometry smaller. This problem has been addressed by the Cesium developers by using what is called a 'promise' -javascript language- which can deal with unresolved URLs and/or broken download links. But, still this is not by any means a proper WFS service.